# SQL Select all rows that matching multiple condition in one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to filter out records based on some text matching in nvarchar(2000) column.

I need record that apply more than condition

All condition may come from another table.
For example, suppose my `TableA` with these records:

```
 ID            RecordNote
 1             1:15&2:30&3:40
 2             2:50&1:40&3:50
 3             2:60&1:30&4:50
 4             3:50&1:40&2:60
 5             7:50&2:40&3:60
```

and `TableB`:

```
 PatternID     Pattern
 1             3:50
 2             2:60
```

I want to select all of the records from `TablA` in which RecordNotes has values 3:50 &2:60

something like this

```
   SELECT * 
   From TableA 
   Where RecordNotes LIKE '%3:50%' 
        AND  RecordNotes LIKE '%2:60%'
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Your fundamental problem is that you have represented the data incorrectly.  You should not be storing lists of things as strings.  You should have another table with one row per `TableA.Id` and `Pattern`.

Comment: originally the pattern was in one column '3:50&1:-1&2:60', I want to search using this pattern but with some conditions 
1- Remove -1 with id, so my pattern will be '3:50&2:60'
2- Remove & because reocrdNotes doesn't store &

so I used the split string function to get a pattern in tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden with `cross apply()` in a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
create table t (ID int,RecordNote varchar(32));
insert into t values 
 (1,'1:15&2:30&3:40')
,(2,'2:50&1:40&3:50')
,(3,'2:60&1:30&4:50')
,(4,'3:50&1:40&2:60')
,(5,'7:50&2:40&3:60');

create table p (patternId int, Pattern varchar(32));
insert into p values  (1,'3:50'),(2,'2:60');

;with cte as (
  select 
      t.Id
    , RecordNote = s.Item
    , RecordNoteMatches = count(*) over (partition by t.Id) 
  from t
    cross apply dbo.delimitedsplit8K(t.RecordNote,'&') s
    inner join p 
      on p.Pattern = s.Item
)
select *
from cte
where RecordNoteMatches = (select count(*) from p);
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/KKTR95367

returns:

```
+----+------------+-------------------+
| Id | RecordNote | RecordNoteMatches |
+----+------------+-------------------+
|  4 | 3:50       |                 2 |
|  4 | 2:60       |                 2 |
+----+------------+-------------------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

---

If you just want the `Id`s of the matches, then you can simplify the query to:

```
;with cte as (
  select 
      t.Id
    , RecordNoteMatches = count(*)
  from t
    cross apply dbo.delimitedsplit8K(t.RecordNote,'&') s
    inner join p 
      on p.Pattern = s.Item
  group by t.Id
)
select *
from cte
where RecordNoteMatches = (select count(*) from p);
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/RDZWF26107

returns:

```
+----+-------------------+
| Id | RecordNoteMatches |
+----+-------------------+
|  4 |                 2 |
+----+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make use of the below code:

```
    CREATE  TABLE TableA (ID INT,RecordNote NVARCHAR(2000))
    INSERT INTO TableA VALUES
    (1,'1:15&2:30&3:40'),
    (2,'2:50&1:40&3:50'),
    (3,'2:60&1:30&4:50'),
    (4,'3:50&1:40&2:60'),
    (5,'7:50&2:40&3:60')


    CREATE  TABLE TableB (PatternID INT,Pattern NVARCHAR(2000))
    INSERT INTO TableB VALUES
     (1,'3:50'),
     (2,'2:60')


    DECLARE @NUMBERS AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    SELECT  @NUMBERS = COALESCE(@NUMBERS + '%'') AND A.RecordNote LIKE (''%', '') + B.Pattern FROM TableB B

    DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @QUERY = 
    'SELECT DISTINCT ID,RecordNote FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B
             ON A.RecordNote LIKE (''%'+@NUMBERS+'%'')'

    EXEC (@QUERY)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, STUFF(RECORDNOTE, 5, 5, '') AS Data
FROM TableA)

SELECT ID, RecordNote FROM CTE WHERE Data = '3:50&2:60'
```

Comment: Try giving more context to your answer. It might solve the problem, but why does this work, and the question authors version not?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;WITH cte1(ID,RecordNote)
 AS
 (
 SELECT 1,'1:15&2:30&3:40'  UNION ALL
 SELECT 2,'2:50&1:40&3:50'  UNION ALL
 SELECT 3,'2:60&1:30&4:50'  UNION ALL
 SELECT 4,'3:50&1:40&2:60'  UNION ALL
 SELECT 5,'7:50&2:40&3:60'  
 )
 ,cte2( PatternID,Pattern)
 AS
 (

 SELECT 1,'3:50' union all
 SELECT 2,'2:60'
 )
SELECT cte2.Pattern,cte1.ID,cte1.RecordNote
FROM cte2
CROSS JOIN cte1
WHERE CHARINDEX(Pattern, Right(RecordNote, CHARINDEX('&', REVERSE(RecordNote)))) > 0
```